# read xml simple element objects into an array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

i have read an xml file but it returns like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 94351
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 94351
            )
    )

 )
```

this is the code i have writen to read from the xml file

```
$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);     
$cart = array();
foreach ($root->Docs as $Docs) {    
    $x = $Docs;
    $cart[] = array($x);
}
}
```

but i want my array to look like this failing to get bellow result. im not getting the bellow result. reason i want bellow result is to compare this array to another array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 94351
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 94352
    )

)
```

Comment: `$cart[] = (string) $x;` ?

Comment: $cart[] = (string) $x; is the answer. this worked

Answer (score 0):

For those, who'll open this question later
Just cast SimpleXMLElement to string

E.g:

```
$cart[] = (string) $x;
```